# not able to work with cx-oracle

Tags: python, oracle, pycharm, cx-oracle

I am new to python and oracle, I have written the code for the connection to oracle database 11g but it gives an error:

```
import cx_Oracle
    con=cx_Oracle.connect('sys/Satyam123@localhost/xe')
    con.close(

)


It gives the following error in pycharm:
```

> C:\Users\DELL\venv\module2\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/PYTHON/module2/check.py Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/PYTHON/module2/check.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       con=cx_Oracle.connect('sys/Satyam123@localhost/xe') cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot
>   be loaded: "The specified module could not be found". See
>   https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help

Answer (score 1):

Please download and install Oracle Client. (There are several editions of Oracle Client, but the instant one will do):

http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/instantclient/122010/instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip

Once it is installed, the cx_Oracle python module will look for the Oracle libs (OCI) and load them.

Comment: I have installed oracle databse 11g, still I have to install oracle client, why? when I have already have oracle databse 11g, what's the difference between the two

Comment: No need for Oracle Client as long as Oracle Database is installed. Make sure 'oci.dll' can be found in your system path %PATH% : C:\>type oci.dll (should be listed)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Please follow the link https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html and install Oracle Instant Client 64-bit or 32-bit as per your system version. Once this is installed python would automatically be able to find Oracle Client libraries and you can successfully connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like,there is issue related to PATH.You can try to install package with the IDE terminal.In your case just try to install a package with pycharm terminal.

After that try to execute below script:

```
import cx_Oracle
import db_config
user="test"
pw="test"
dsn="localhost:port/TEST" #here TEST is service id

con = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pw, dsn)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from test_table")
res = cur.fetchall()
for row in res:
    print(row)
```

Still having an issue then you can refer :

[https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-Scripting-for-the-Future.html]

Comment: I reckon the issue was more likely to be a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem.  Python and  Oracle client libraries need to be the same architecture.   In this question, Python was 32-bit (as shown by the message looking for 32-bit libraries)  and there is a good chance that XE was 64-bit.  The solution would have been to install 64-bit Python, or install 32-bit Instant Client.